# Getting error when using nuget pack for a solution with some unsafe code

Tags: c#, nuget, unsafe, pack

I am currently trying to pack a nuget package for solution with some unsafe code.
It's running fine with MSBuild because I am able to give it the following parameter: `/p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true`

I have tried several way to give the same parameter to my nuget.exe pack command.

```
".\.nuget\nuget.exe" pack "My.csproj" -Build -IncludeReferencedProjects -Version 02.06.5 -verbosity detailed -suffix UAT -Properties "Configuration=Release AllowUnsafeBlocks=true" 


".\.nuget\nuget.exe" pack "My.csproj" -Build -IncludeReferencedProjects -Version 02.06.5 -verbosity detailed -suffix UAT -Properties "Configuration=Release" "AllowUnsafeBlocks=true"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error CS0227: Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe
```

EDIT: It's also running fine from VS becase the solution is well setup :)

Comment: Have you allowed Allow unsafe code in your project properties?

Comment: Yes I did, otherwise I would not be able to build it directly from VS2019 :)

Comment: And what about doing the same in any other project that has a reference to it?

Comment: You should maybe add "(from VS)" after MSBuild because it wasn't clear for everyone (including me, my bad). I assume you have looked trough [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack)?

Comment: Yes, I haven't found anything related to unsafe : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019

Comment: But now you're linking to msbuild? Isn't your problem only with nuget?

Comment: Related to the documentation you have posted as link, I need to send some information to the msbuild to tell him that I am going to compile with unsafe flag set to true. Apparently the only way to do that is by passing Properties parameters: this is related to the msbuild documentation : Should appear last on the command line after other options. Specifies a list of properties that override values in the project file; see Common MSBuild Project Properties for property names.

Comment: Is your project using SDK style projects, or `PackageReference`? If so, you should pack with `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:pack`, rather than `nuget pack`. I'm not sure that would avoid the issue, it sounds more like a project configuration issue, but maybe it would help.

Comment: no SDK Projects style sorry :/. I have found the solution :) see my response.

Comment: `nuget pack` doesn't pack traditional projects using `PackageReference` properly either, from memory dependencies won't come through. Also the first solution found doesn't always mean the best solution, so just making sure that your package get created correctly.

Comment: Yes my package is fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is really simple....
Add ';' between each -Properties parameters.

```
".\.nuget\nuget.exe" pack "My.csproj" -Build -IncludeReferencedProjects -Version 02.06.5 -verbosity detailed -suffix UAT -Properties "Configuration=Release;AllowUnsafeBlocks=true"
```